# convert roman to number got index out of range error

Tags: python, roman-numerals

I am new to python. Trying to convert roman to numbers. Everything works perfect but when I input some roman terms I got index error. Please trace out the error and correct me.

```
def roman(x):
    x=list(x)
    print(x)
    s=0
    val=[['I',1],['V',5],['X',10],['L',50],['C',100],['D',500],['M',1000]]
    val=dict(val)


while x:

    a=val[x[0]]
    b=val[x[1]]
    print('a----',a)
    print('b----',b)
    if (a>=b):
        s=s+a
        x=x[1:]
    else:
        s=s+b-a
        x=x[2:]
return s

x=input("Enter roman characters to convert to decimal: ")
x=x.upper()
a=roman(x)
print(a)
```

When I input 'IXC, IVX' these terms I got index error. Why it is not accepting 'I'. The output I got is shown:

[image]

Comment: IXC is not a valid Roman number; IX and XC are valid (9 and 90 respectively), but not the triad.  Similarly with IVX; IV and IX are valid, but IVX is not.  (What values were you expecting for IXC and IVX, anyway?)

Comment: But when I convert this roman terms using online converter I got 89 and for ivx I got 4 as output.. [check this link](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/roman_decimal/)

Comment: You could report the bug to the site if you like.  Just because it is online doesn't make it correct.  What does it give for VXC — 85?  Yes, I could go look, but I'm being lazy.  I have a program called `roman`.  When run as: `roman 89 4 iv iiii lxxxix lxxxviiii ixc ivx` it gives eight answers:
`LXXXIX`, `IV`, `4`, `4`, `89`, `89`,
`roman: Failed to convert ixc to arabic`, and
`roman: Failed to convert ivx to arabic`.  That doesn't prove anything more than the site you mention does, of course.  See also Wikipedia on [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals).

Answer (score 2):

Can you instead try the roman package:

```
>>> import roman
>>> roman.fromRoman('X')
10
>>> roman.fromRoman('IV')
4
>>> roman.fromRoman('V')
5
>>> roman.fromRoman('M')
1000
>>> roman.fromRoman('L')
50
>>>
```

As for the error, Jonathan has correctly pointed out:

```
>>> roman.fromRoman('IXC')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sharad/trials/udev_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/roman.py", line 72, in fromRoman
    raise InvalidRomanNumeralError('Invalid Roman numeral: %s' % s)
roman.InvalidRomanNumeralError: Invalid Roman numeral: IXC
>>> 

>>> roman.fromRoman('IVX')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sharad/trials/udev_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/roman.py", line 72, in fromRoman
    raise InvalidRomanNumeralError('Invalid Roman numeral: %s' % s)
roman.InvalidRomanNumeralError: Invalid Roman numeral: IVX
>>>
```

The IndexError: list index out of range is due to:

In the while loop,

```
iteration#1
a = 1
b = 10
1 >= 10 => false
```

so, the code enters the else block:

```
x=x[2:] # x = ['C'] for IXC as input OR x = ['X'] for IVX as input
```

---

```
iteration#2

# x only has a single element
a=val[x[0]] # success
b=val[x[1]] # crashes, since x only has a single element
```

Comment: I'd personally prefer using the 'roman' library :) As for handling the crash, I'll create a list of patterns that denote a valid roman number in accordance with the rules at http://www.factmonster.com/ipka/A0769547.html

Comment: I agree with u **Sharad** but if I want to try with direct initialisation I want to change the while loop. And the value should not get crashed.. what should I place in while loop